# pywinauto определение полей foxpro

Tags: python, pywinauto

есть программа на foxpro с бд которую нет возможности выгрузить в файл
необходимо перенести все данные из программы в веб приложение
проблема в том что при открытии карточки количество полей в разных карточках не одинаково
т.е. в одной карточке имеется поле "автор" а в другой её нет. и при переносе данные можно перепутать а через коннект необходимые поля не определяются
пример

карточка1
поле1 автор пупкин и.и.
поле2 издание питер
поле3 инвентарный номер 111111

карточка 2
поле1 издание питер
поле2 инвентарный номер 111112
поле3 код 1

в итоге в веб приложении карточка 2 перенесется неверно
т.е. поле 1 где должен быть автор будет издание
есть ли возможность как то распознать поля?

Comment: Ну, можно на статик тексты вызывать метод `.exists()` и если False, то пропускать это поле. Если нужно подробней в коде, то приведите кусок кода и скриншоты хорошо бы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

открыл исполняемый файл при помощи среды разработки foxpro, подключился при помощи pywinauto, прочитал структуру, вывел необходимые значения value

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]